# Prove the sequence is convergent

Tags: analysis

Prove: if a subsequence $\{x_{k_i}\}$ of a monotonic sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent，the monotonic sequence $\{x_n\}$ is also convergent.

Are there any mistakes in my proof?

Proof: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a monotonic increasing sequence. Because the subsequence $\{x_{k_i}\}$ is monotonic and convergent, it has a supremum: call it $m$. Then $m \geq x_{k_i} \geq x_n$. Thus, the sequence $\{x_n\}$has a supremum. Because $\{x_n\}$ is monotonic increasing, it is convergent.

Comment: When you write $m\geqslant x_{k_i}\geqslant x_n$, what is $i$, what is $k_i$, and what is $n$? Why do we have $x_{k_i}\geqslant x_n$?

Comment: oh sorry I correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then $m \geq x_{k_i} \geq x_n$ .The sequence$\{x_n\}$has a supremum...

The above excerpt takes a little work to *shore up*.

You are given that:

- $~m~$ is **an** upper bound to the subsequence.
- $~m~$ is the least upper bound to the subsequence.

You then have to show that

- $~m~$ is **an** upper bound to the sequence.
- $~m~$ is the least upper bound to the sequence.

This takes some work.

---

First, assume that $~m~$ is not an upper bound to the sequence.  This implies that there exists an $~x_n~$ such that $~x_n > m.$

However, since $~\langle x_{k_i}\rangle~$ is assumed to be a strictly increasing (infinite) convergent subsequence, there must exist an element $~x_{k_i}~$ of this subsequence such that $~x_{k_i} > x_n.~$

Then, you have that

- $~x_n > m.$
- $~x_n < x_{k_i} \leq m.~$

This yields a contradiction.  Therefore, the premise that $~m~$ is not **an** upper bound to the sequence must be false.  Therefore, $~m~$ must be **an** upper bound to the sequence.

For the record, the above work, by itself, is sufficient to solve the original problem.  That is, it is now known that **an** upper bound to the original sequence exists.

Therefore, the original sequence is strictly increasing and bounded above.

Therefore, the original sequence must be convergent.

However, in the spirit of the specific proof offered by the original poster, the next section is included to provide the (now redundant) proof that $~m~$ must be the least upper bound to the original sequence.

---

Suppose that there exists an $~m_1 < m~$ such that $~m_1~$ is an upper bound to the original sequence.  Since the subsequence is a subset of the original sequence, this implies that $~m_1~$ is an upper bound to the subsequence.  Since $~m_1~$ is assumed $~< m,~$ this contradicts the assumption that $~m~$ is the least upper bound to the subsequence.

Therefore, the assumption that $~m_1~$ is an upper bound to the sequence has led to a contradiction.  Therefore, $~m~$ must be the least upper bound to the sequence.